# R convert to percentages

Tags: r, percentage

I have my code:

```
fun_max <- 13
fun_min <- -1

set.seed(50)
x <- rnorm(1000, fun_min, 1)
x1 <- rnorm(1000, fun_max, 1)
C <- c(0, 0.01, 0.1, 1)

fun <- function(C, a, b) {
  1/(2 + (C/a)^b) 
}

a <- 1
b <- 1



mlist <- list()
for (i in 1:length(C)) {
  fun_C <- fun_max*fun(C[i], a, b)
  x3 <- rnorm(1000, fun_C, 1)
  mlist[i] <- mean(x3)
  y3 <- hist(x3, plot=FALSE, breaks=25)
  m_h <- unlist(mlist)
  mlist[[i]] <- mean(x3)
}
```

I'd like to improve my code by changing the means value to a percentage, assuming the fun max value as 100 percent. To make the results in the mlist show in the form of percentages and not means, for example 0 .65 0.55. I don't really know how to do it in R (I'm not very familiar with R) so I'm asking for help in this forum

Comment: `mlist[i] <- mean(x3)/fun_max`? Sometimes when working in a new programming language, trying to think "how'd I solve this in X" (X being excel, stata, python or where you've worked before) and replicating this in R works out magic

Comment: Oliver thank you for your response. So mlist[i] <- mean(x3)/fun_max takes fun_max as 100 percent if I understand correctly?

Comment: Do I think right Oliver ?

Comment: Yup, at this point it is understanding the math and not R :-)